# Trying to get my ERC tokens from etherscsan back into my etherwallet

Tags: erc-20

How can I get my Erc-20 tokens back into my Etherwallet.  they show up in my Etherscan, but they are not in my Etherwallet.

I had to get a new computer, because Microsoft tried to download a new version of windows 10, and fdailed leaving me to get a new computer.

I have my Metamask seed, and I can see my exact tokens and balance, in etherscan, which everything looks to be in order, but I cannot get them to show in my etherwallet

I wish there was somebody I could see in person about this that knows about this, buty any help you may be able to give would be great thanks

Bret Kubin
Kubs69@gmail.com

Comment: If you have the seed you can access your account from MEW, it provides seed as one of the alternatives for the private key.

Comment: First of all remove ur email, u will get scammed so hard. U should use ur seed in metamask (make sure u have the original metamask and not a clone or fake, before giving the seed) then add the tokens (Add Token) each token has a smart contract, u can get its address if u click on the token name in etherscan.

Comment: To be clear etherscan don’t have or access ur tokens and ether, it just show the balances and state of the blockchain

Comment: If ur token shown in metamask then it means the selected account in metamask has then and can transfer them.

Answer (score 0):

- **How can I get my Erc-20 tokens back into my Etherwallet. they show up
  in my Etherscan, but they are not in my Etherwallet.**

You must "watch" the contract for that. At the bottom rigth, there is a butto nto add a custom token. You need the contract address, the symbol and the decimals and there you go! (the contract address can be found in your transaction information)

Comment: I tried adding a token, it was ATM Chain, worth not much, that I own, so that I could test what yo were saying about the contract address.  Well it added the token, but not my balance.  Now I know Etherscan is down right now, so I had my contract address that I saved and took a picture of, so that is how I was still able to put it in, and add the coin, but it says zero.  what is the action now.  Do I need to wait until Etherscan is back up, or is there another issue I may need to hurdle

Comment: Check your transaction state using an other chain explorer like this one: https://www.etherchain.org/  (I have not used it before though)

Comment: I've got all my ether tokens in my etherwallet, and I can view them on etherscan as well, with contract address and all, but the options when they come up when you want to send or recieve tokesn in my etherwallet, I found by using my public account

Comment: so that does not allow me to send any, it is just viewing my wallet.  When I put my private key, it does not allow me access.  Or my metamask phrase.

Comment: I can see them all in my public address, but how do I have access to trade or if I want to cash them out

Comment: since I can see the wallet, and it is all in tact on my ether wallet, how do I get them accessible if my private key or metamask phrase will not import them

Comment: So basically to clear the air, I found a way to get all my coins in my ether wallet, yae, but I can only view them in the view your tokens

Comment: I tried using my private key, and my 12 word phrases and it gets me to a different address.

Comment: but when I go into etherscan and click on contract address, all my coins are there as well.  Just like they were before microsoft tried downloading or tried to download the a newer version of windows 10

Comment: so from there, or if need from etherscan how can we get to my coins